The getter 'MyRoutes' isn't defined for the class 'MyApp'
I have two screens in my app 1. homepage 2. loginpage and I want to navigate from login page to homepage on a button click through routes.
the routes are define in separate file utils(folder)=>Routes.dart....but it gives the following error when I run the app..
lib/main.dart:21:9: Error: The getter 'MyRoutes' isn't defined for the class 'MyApp'.

'MyApp' is from 'package:flutter_first_vs/main.dart' ('lib/main.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'MyRoutes'.
MyRoutes.homeRoute: (context) => HomePage(),

main.lib
  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
  themeMode: ThemeMode.dark,
  darkTheme: ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.light),
  theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.amber),
  //initialRoute: "/login",
  home: const LoginPage(),
  routes: {
  MyRoutes.homeRoute: (context) => const HomePage(),
  MyRoutes.loginRoute: (context) => const LoginPage(),
   },
);

}
}
the required images are attached
the code is correct and not giving any error in IDE but when I run the app it gives the error
image i

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Also, please provide a [mre]; this code alone is not enough to reproduce your problem.

Please share the code that the error is coming from.

home: const LoginPage(),
routes: {
MyRoutes.homeRoute: (context) => const HomePage(),
MyRoutes.loginRoute: (context) => const LoginPage(),
},

this the code in the main.lib

you can see the code in the question which is modified

@farmanullah Please read the first link I sent you. Code should not be in images; there is almost always a better way to express it in text.
